# Angularfire $onAuth not firing after $authWithOAuthPopUp using Ionic and Cordova in app browser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I'm working on an Ionic app that uses Twitter login through an OAuth pop up and redirects from the login page to the main dashboard. It works fine on Desktop, but when compiled as an ionic app (Android in this case) the login window opens, redirects back to the app, but then nothing happens - neither of the two functions (redirect to the dashboard page, and create a new user) fire.

I've read pretty much every similar question and tutorial on this and just can't find the issue. I've got the Cordova in app browser installed to handle the popup, and I've tried callback functions, $timeouts, $onAuth watching - all work perfectly on a browser, and in the in-browser emulator ionic provides, but not at all when compiled to an app on the phone.

Any help is massively appreciated.

My current code in my controller:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    Auth.auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect('twitter').then(function(authData) {
        // User successfully logged in
    }).catch(function(error) {
        if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
            Auth.auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('twitter').then(function(authData) {
                // User successfully logged in. We can log to the console
                // since we’re using a popup here
                console.log(authData);
            });
        } else {
            // Another error occurred
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};

// Update profile and forward to homepage
Auth.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {

    console.log('Logged in as', authData.uid);
    console.log(authData);

    // Update/Create profile
    Auth.new(authData);
    // Forward to homepage
    $state.go('tab.dash');
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error code inside your console? I'm getting an error, so I'd check your console too.

Comment: In my case, I made the mistake of not having the whitelist plugin installed.
I have a sample app you can reference here

Comment: @mhartington I actually love you. Of all the many many MANY tutorials/questions I read on this only [one](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-user-authentication) mentions whitelisting and it's sort of described as optional. There's even an updated version of that guide that doesn't mention it at all. Thank you so much! I will put the information in as the answer so others might find a solution

Answer (score 0):

As @mhartington points out the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) needs to be installed and the following two lines added to the config.xml as per this [tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-user-authentication)

```
<allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com" />
<allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com" />
```

Hope this helps anyone else banging their heads against a brick wall with this!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just needed to add the whitelist plugin and allow access to the firebase urls